# How does Apache Spark handle non-Spark code?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I create a Spark job (in Java) which includes Spark code (using the Dataset API) and non-Spark code. It seems like the Spark code will be automatically parallelized and run on multiple machines. Does Spark know to run the the regular-Java/non-Spark on only one machine?

Answer (score 0):

Spark programs are standard Scala / Java programs. Unless you explicitly use distribution / parallelization primitives, codes run exactly as is.  So to answer:

> Does Spark know to run the the regular-Java/non-Spark on only one machine?

it just doesn't care. For the JVM it is plain code.